# How can I use one ImageList control for all forms in my project?

Tags: c#, winforms, imagelist

I've an imageList control with a bunch of icons in my main form. I want to use these icons on other forms as well. How can i do this? Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a user control. They are valuable for reuse like this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reuse the entire ImageList, or would it be enough to just reuse the images themselves?

Usually you would do the latter, for which there is a very easy way built-in.

Under your project node in the Solution Explorer, expand `Properties` and double-click `Resources.resx`. Click `Add Resource` > Add `Existing File`. Browse to your icons/images and add them. This is the preferred way to add resources to your project.

Now anywhere you want to use an icon/image, from the forms designer you'll be able to select these files in the "Select Resource" dialog that pops up when you click the `...` button on an image property in the property grid.

You can also access them in code, e.g.

```
   BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImageFile;
```